# Get Headers from Post Response

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, bearer-token, angular10

I am calling a .NET Core Web API using `http.post`.

My only problem is that I'd like to also read a header value from the HTTP response object, namely, the bearer token. Is there a way that I could this?

```
var user = this.http
        .post<User>(this.loginUrl, body, { 'headers': headers })
        .pipe(map(user => {
           //do stuff with user data here
            return user;
        }))
```

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 0):

By passing an anonymous object to the `options` parameter that has an `observe` property of `response` I was able to access the headers in the response from the POST method in the Web API:

```
    const httpOptions: { headers; observe; } = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        }),
        observe: 'response'
    };

    var user = this.http
        .post<User>(this.loginUrl, body, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(event => {
            //the checking of the HttpEventType is not strictly necessary
            if (event.type == HttpEventType.Response)
            {
                let user = event.body;
                let headers = event.headers
                //do stuff with user data and headers
                return user;
            }
        }))
```

The [HttpEvent](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent) then exposes the headers and body as properties.